# Javascript replacing all numbers with RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Very simple question for one of you:

This is my replace:

```
var tid = 1412;
var counter = 1;
var oldHtml = "
<tr data-rid="1412" class="fields-tr-container">
  <td rel="naam[1412]">Wat voor entree ticket is dit</td> 
  <td rel="max_tickets[1412]">50</td>                                       
</tr>";

var regex = new RegExp("\["+tid+"\]", "ig");
return oldHTML.replace(regex, '[new_'+counter+']');
```

Now this is the result:

```
<tr data-rid="1412" class="fields-tr-container">
  <td rel="naam[[new_1][new_1][new_1][new_1]]">Wat voor entree ticket is dit</td> 
  <td rel="max_tickets[[new_1][new_1][new_1][new_1]]">50</td>                                       
</tr>
```

And this is wat i want:

```
<tr data-rid="1412" class="fields-tr-container">
  <td rel="naam[new_1]">Wat voor entree ticket is dit</td> 
  <td rel="max_tickets[new_1]">50</td>                                       
</tr>
```

Thanks if you know the (probably easy) solution.

Comment: You're mixing quotes badly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must escape the `\` in a string literal.

Change

```
var regex = new RegExp("\["+tid+"\]", "ig");
```

to

```
var regex = new RegExp("\\["+tid+"\\]", "ig");
```